# Rolling your own generic views in Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views

The Django documentation mentions in the Class-based generic views that the DetailView is composed from: View, SingleObjectMixin, and SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.  I am experimenting with this, as I am interested in creating a generic view that will do an object_detail view with a ModelForm so that my model rows can be generated automatically.

To try to duplicate the DetailView I tried to create a class as follows:

```
from django.views.generic import list_detail, View
from django.views.generic.detail import (SingleObjectMixin,
    SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDetailView)

class formdisplay(View,SingleObjectMixin,SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin): pass
```

When I use formdisplay instead of list_detail.object_detail I get the error

```
TypeError at /inpatient-detail/4/
__init__() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (2 given)
```

Any hints at how to do this?

Also, where is the documentation on how to write the import statements? I had to google to find what to import from as I couldn't find that in the documentation.

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: How are you using `formdisplay` in your url conf?  `formdisplay.as_view()`? Plus you might want to do what is already built-in to Django. Check `django.views.generic.edit` and their `FormView` classes.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a single line way to leverage my ModelForm. The object_detail function is nice but won't take a form as input. I see now that i can do what I want by rewriting object_detail for a ModelView or by using the class based generic views and replacing the get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As django's documentation on class-based generic view is still not very state-of-the-art, the best thing to get more information about them is to browse the source code; for create/update views [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/edit.py) is a good start.

When inheriting from multiple classes/mixins you should also keep an eye on their order - if you look at django's source you'll see they put the Mixins *before* the other classes!

It's not totally clear to me, what you are trying to achieve, but if your goal is to display a form with data from an existing object, [`django.views.generic.update.UpdateView`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/edit.py#L198) should be your friend!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the source. I now see that list_detail.object_detail is actually a function and the comments about class views is really saying to move to the class based generic views that can be used with mixins.

Comment: The answer is available on http://stackoverflow.com/q/6564068/820321

Thanks to everyone.  The comments to the related questions allowed me to figure this out. Couldn't have done this without you!